# Powershell xaml RichText window not updating Real time

Tags: powershell, xaml, user-interface

I'm trying to make a Error detection and Logging Function, Outputing to a Log File and a Rich Text Box in the UI of my App (Xaml).

This works, but not real time.

in my VSStudio console it works fine, the console lines come up when they run, but when I write to my RichTextBox it only gets updated after all my commands ran.
These are my functions

```
Function GotError 
{
    if ($error)
    {        
        Logit "$error" "red"
    } else
    { 
        Logit "OK!" "Green"
    }
    $error.clear()
}
    
Function LogIt ($mymsg, $myColor)
{
    #Just for Debugging Pourposes
    Tee-Object -InputObject ($mymsg) -FilePath $loggingFolder\$logFile | Write-Host -ForegroundColor $myColor    
    $RichTextRange = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.TextRange( 
        $WPFRTextbox_Console.Document.ContentEnd,$WPFRTextbox_Console.Document.ContentEnd )         
        $RichTextRange.Text = $mymsg + "`r"
    $RichTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue( ( [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::ForegroundProperty ), $myColor ) 
}

Function ResetGroupPolicies
{
    LogIt "Reseting Group Policies..." "Black"
    if (Test-Path "$env:windir\System32\GroupPolicyUsers")
    {
        LogIt "Removing user Group Policies" "Black"
        Remove-Item "$env:windir\System32\GroupPolicyUsers" -Recurse -Force        
        GotError
    } else 
    {
        LogIt "User Group Policies don't exist" "Yellow"
    }
    if (Test-Path "$env:windir\System32\GroupPolicy")
    {        
        LogIt "Removing General Group Policies" "Black"
        Remove-Item "$env:windir\System32\GroupPolicy" -Recurse -Force        
        GotError
    } else 
    {
        Logit "General Policies don't exist" "Yellow"
    }    
    Logit "Updating Group Policies" "Black"    
    gpupdate /force
}
```

In my VSStudio Console it's all displayed when it's suposed to, but on my UI it's all displayed only after gpupdate Finishes

[This is what happens in my Console, Real time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUIAx.jpg)

[This comes in all at once, in my Rich Text Box once gpupdate finishes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBqS6.jpg)

Any Help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Found an Answer to refresh the Form/Textbox Realtime

```
function LogIt ($mymsg, $myColor)
{
    #Just for Debugging Pourposes
    if ($myColor -eq "Orange")
    {
        Tee-Object -InputObject ($mymsg) -FilePath $loggingFolder\$logFile -Append | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow
    } else 
    {
        Tee-Object -InputObject ($mymsg) -FilePath $loggingFolder\$logFile -Append | Write-Host -ForegroundColor $myColor
    }    
    $RichTextRange = New-Object System.Windows.Documents.TextRange( 
        $WPFRTextbox_Console.Document.ContentEnd,$WPFRTextbox_Console.Document.ContentEnd )         
        $RichTextRange.Text = $mymsg
    $RichTextRange.ApplyPropertyValue( ( [System.Windows.Documents.TextElement]::ForegroundProperty ), $myColor)    
    $form.Dispatcher.Invoke(
        [action]{$WPFRTextbox_Console.AppendText("`r")},
        "Render"
    )
    $WPFRTextbox_Console.ScrollToEnd()
}
```

Reference:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/941061-powershell-gui-wpf-xaml-need-help-updating-the-form-in-real-time